# LaTeX Error: File hopatch.sty not found

Tags: color, packages, oberdiek

There was an update on the package `hopatch` without sty inside on 17th August 2020.

I want to downgrade this package with one which contains an sty file.

Does anyone know how to downgrade a package with MiKTeX on Windows?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Unfortunately not, there are only 'hopatch.tpm', 'README.md' and, 'hopatch.pdf'

Comment: then something went wrong at the miktex side, what was submitted to ctan (and what got installed in texlive) included hopatch.sty and  hopatch-2016-05-16.sty (the latter is called internally in some cases)

Comment: However, the last update of hopatch was on 17 August 2020 ...

Comment: I know when it was (13th august) , I submitted it to ctan:-)

Comment: as a temporary workaround take hopatch.dtx from https://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/hopatch  run tex on hopatch.dtx and it will generate the two .sty files, put them in the same folder as your document.

Comment: I added an issue for miktex https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex/issues/606